# Using JSON files in Google Maps styling

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I'm having a bit of a nightmare with this Google Maps custom styling wizard.

Ok, I have my map and it loads fine, but I am trying to add my JSON file to custom style the thing and I get an error.

**Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection**

Also the error seems to come from a file called main.js - but I have a file called main.js and it doesn't have this code in it.

Here is my code in the **head** of my document.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
// Create a simple map.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
zoom: 16,
center: {lat: 53.668398, lng: -2.167713}
});

// Load a GeoJSON from the same server as our demo.
map.data.loadGeoJson('http://pixelsandcode.local:5757/map.json');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

My JSON code:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#ffffff" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#efefef" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "water",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "color": "#dedddd" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "color": "#efefef" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? This is my first go at doing maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing the JSON to [style a map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) which is what you get out of the [Map Styling Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) and the GeoJSON used by the [data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer)

They go in different places and do different things.  To style the map, put the "style" data in the [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) styles property.

The data layer is used for displaying geographic information on the map (markers, polygons, polylines,...), not styling the map tiles.

Working code snippet with your map styles (if you want to load them from an external file, you can, but you wouldn't use the data layer, you would just assign the styling data to a global variable and use that for the styles property):

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  // Create a simple map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: {
      lat: 53.668398,
      lng: -2.167713
    },
    styles: [{
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#efefef"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "water",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "color": "#dedddd"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "color": "#efefef"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    }]
  });

  // Load a GeoJSON from the same server as our demo.
  //map.data.loadGeoJson('http://pixelsandcode.local:5757/map.json');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to something like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
zoom: 16,
center: {lat: 53.668398, lng: -2.167713},
styles: [
        {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#ffffff" }
          ]
          },{
              "featureType": "poi",
              "elementType": "geometry",
              "stylers": [
                  { "color": "#efefef" }
              ]
          },{
              "featureType": "water",
              "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "off" }
              ]
          },{
              "featureType": "road",
              "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
              "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#dedddd" }
              ]
          },{
              "featureType": "road",
              "elementType": "geometry.fill",
              "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" },
                  { "color": "#efefef" }
              ]
          },{
              "featureType": "poi",
              "elementType": "labels.icon",
              "stylers": [
                  { "visibility": "on" }
              ]
          }


        ]
})
```